# How to return an object whose nested objects match a list of search strings?

Tags: javascript, recursion, search

I'm trying to return an object that is a collection of objects that match a given list of search strings.

**Testing Data Structure**

```
var data = {
  "tabs-1": {
    "test 1": {
      "test 2": {
        "test 3a": {
          "tab1graph1": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3b": {
          "tab1graph2": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3c": {
          "tab1graph3": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Input**

```
var searchList = ["apple", "orange", "test 3b", "test 3a"];
```

**Current code that only returns one match, and not both expected matches:**

```
function searchObjectForValues(obj, searchList) {
  var matchingObjects = {};

  function recursiveSearch(currentObj, path) {
    if (typeof currentObj === 'object' && currentObj !== null) {
      for (var key in currentObj) {
        if (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var value = currentObj[key];
          var currentPath = path.concat(key);

          if (searchList.includes(key)) {
            matchingObjects[key] = currentObj[key];
          }

          recursiveSearch(value, currentPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  recursiveSearch(obj, []);

  return matchingObjects;
}
```

```js
function searchObjectForValues(obj, searchList) {
  var matchingObjects = {};

  function recursiveSearch(currentObj, path) {
    if (typeof currentObj === 'object' && currentObj !== null) {
      for (var key in currentObj) {
        if (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var value = currentObj[key];
          var currentPath = path.concat(key);

          if (searchList.includes(key)) {
            matchingObjects[key] = currentObj[key];
          }

          recursiveSearch(value, currentPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  recursiveSearch(obj, []);

  return matchingObjects;
}

var data = {
  "tabs-1": {
    "test 1": {
      "test 2": {
        "test 3a": {
          "tab1graph1": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3b": {
          "tab1graph2": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3c": {
          "tab1graph3": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var searchList = ["apple", "testx3", "test 3b", "test 3a"];

var result = searchObjectForValues(data, searchList);
console.log(result);
```

How can I modify this function to return just the

```
"tab1graph1": {
    "String a": "value a",
    "String b": "value b",
    "String c": "value c"
}
```

part and not the "test 3a" above it?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't include an additional matching string that should return.

In the above example, the expected result would be:
{
  "test 3a": {
    "tab1graph1": {
      "String a": "value a",
      "String b": "value b",
      "String c": "value c"
    }
  }
} 
AND
{
  "test 3b": {
    "tab1graph1": {
      "String a": "value a",
      "String b": "value b",
      "String c": "value c"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please add that to the question. It's also not necessary to write the sample data and code twice. The code in the executable snippet is enough.

Comment: You don't have `test 3b` in `searchList` in the snippet.

Comment: When I replace `testx3` with `test 3b` I get the desired result.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't include the second part of my question. I was so focused on getting all the existing code right .... :(

Comment: Use `return Object.values(matchingObjects)` to just return an array of values without the keys.

Comment: *smacks head* That did it! Thank you!

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: You don't, since no answer was posted. It's too trivial to bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**simple composition**

Performing a `search` for many values is a matter of calling `search1` on each value -

```js
function *search(data, values) {
  for (const value of values)
    yield *search1(data, value)
}
```

Writing `search1` is now easier -

```js
function *search1(data, value) {
  if (Object(data) === data) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
      if (key === value)
        yield data[key]
      else
        yield *search1(data[key], value)
    }
  }
}
```

Now we call `search` with our data and search list -

```js
var searchList = ["apple", "testx3", "test 3b", "test 3a"]

for (const result of search(data, searchList))
  console.log(result)
```

Each result is logged. Alternatively use `Array.from` to collect all results in an array -

```js
{
  "tab1graph2": {
    "String a": "value a",
    "String b": "value b",
    "String c": "value c"
  }
}
{
  "tab1graph1": {
    "String a": "value a",
    "String b": "value b",
    "String c": "value c"
  }
}
```

**demo**

Verify the results in your own browser below -

```js
const data = {
  "tabs-1": {
    "test 1": {
      "test 2": {
        "test 3a": {
          "tab1graph1": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3b": {
          "tab1graph2": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        },
        "test 3c": {
          "tab1graph3": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function *search1(data, value) {
  if (Object(data) === data) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
      if (key === value)
        yield data[key]
      else
        yield *search1(data[key], value)
    }
  }
}

function *search(data, values) {
  for (const value of values)
    yield *search1(data, value)
}

var searchList = ["apple", "testx3", "test 3b", "test 3a"];

for (const result of search(data, searchList))
  console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**higher-order function with predicate**

Per @Scott's comment, the solution above can be adapted to use a predicate function -

```js
function *search(data, predicate) {
  if (Object(data) === data) {
    for (const entry of Object.entries(data)) {
      if (predicate(entry))
        yield entry[1]
      else
        yield *search(entry[1], predicate)
    }
  }
}
```

```js
Array.from(
  search(
    data,
    ([key, value]) => searchList.includes(key)
  )
)
```

**sequential search**

In a comment you seek the possibility to find sequential keys, for example `key1->key2`. To support this, we will change the single `value` field to `path`, which represents an array of strings.

```js
function *search1(data, path) {
  if (key.length === 0)
    yield data
  else if (Object(data) === data) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(data)) {
      if (data[key] === path[0])
        yield *search1(data[key], path.slice(1))
      else
        yield *search1(data[key], path)
    }
  }
}
```

`search` stays the same but now you call it with an **array of paths** -

```js
for (const result of search(data, [
  ["test 1", "test 3a"], // test 1 -> test 3a
  ["test 2", "String a"] // test 2 -> String a
]) {
  console.log(result)
}
```

```js
{                               //
  "tab1graph1": {               //
    "String a": "value a",      // matches for:
    "String b": "value b",      // test 1 -> test 3a
    "String c": "value c"       //
  }                             //
}                               //
value a               // matches for:
value a               // test 2 -> String a
value a               //
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than my attempt. Could this be modified to accept a pair of search inputs for more granular results? E.g., var searchList = ["test 2", "test 3a"]; to return only "tab1graph1": {
            "String a": "value a",
            "String b": "value b",
            "String c": "value c"
          }
?

Comment: It's good to see you around, @Mulan.  See my answer for a different approach, and a comparison between them.

Comment: @NFSBuff: What would that mean when the results are nested inside one another like that?  If there was a third input, `["test 2", "test 3a", "String b"]`, should it return just `"value b"`?  And what would happen with non-nested matches?  It sounds quite confusing.

Comment: Apologies, I'll try and clarify. If the data to search has multiple "test 3a" keys, but only one combination of "test 2" and "test 3a", it would return only the one "test 3a" that could be reached by matching "test 2 -> test3a" branch.

Comment: I would suggest opening up a separate question for that.  It's enough different that it will just get confusing trying to update answers here.  You can add a link back to this question for clarification.  Once you do, you can edit this question to add a link to the new one as well.

Comment: @NFSBuff i added a demo for sequential search. currently the specified keys can be at any depth but must be encountered in order. for example, a path of `["b", "d"]` would match value at `a.b.c.d` because `b` and `d` appear in order, regardless of `a` before and `c` occurring in between. if you want the paths to be strict, always matching from a root key, without unspecified descendant keys, that would require a slightly different algorithm. let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: That's great work, Mulan! Thank you for taking the time. Based on initial use thus far it doesn't appear I'll need paths to be strict.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to write a fairly generic `deepFilter` function which includes in its output array all nodes -- at whatever depth -- that match the predicate function supplied.  Then we can configure it with a predicate function that matches against your list of search keys, and call it with your data:

```js
const deepFilter = (pred) => (o) => 
  Object(o) === o
    ? Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) => [
        ...(pred(v, k) ? [v] : []),
        ...deepFilter(pred) (v)
      ])
    : []

const deepFindKeys = (keys) =>
  deepFilter((_, k) => keys.includes(k))

const data = {"tabs-1": {"test 1": {"test 2": {"test 3a": {tab1graph1: {"String a": "value a", "String b": "value b", "String c": "value c"}}, "test 3b": {tab1graph2: {"String a": "value a", "String b": "value b", "String c": "value c"}}, "test 3c": {tab1graph3: {"String a": "value a", "String b": "value b", "String c": "value c"}}}}}}

console.log(deepFindKeys(["apple", "testx3", "test 3b", "test 3a"])(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Our function `deepFindKeys` takes the keys and returns the function returned when we pass a simple key-matching predicate to `deepFilter`.  `deepFilter` has the real substance.  If the input is not an object, we return an empty array.  If it is, we flatmap its entries, for each one, including the value if the predicate matches and recurring on the value.

Most commonly when we want to search to match a predicate, we want to test the value, not the key, so the predicate is supplied the value first; it can ignore the key if it wants.  Here we actually want to test the key and ignore the value, so we pass `(_, k)` where the `_` calls attention to the fact that we just want to skip the first value.

### A Comparison

The answer from Mulan is quite different from this one.  They introduce different sorts of flexibility.  In `deepFilter`, the main function here, we use a generic approach to how we wish to match our objects.  It makes this reusable across a wide swath of search functions.  But it will always traverse the entire tree.  There's no way to stop after, say,  the first five hits.

Mulan's `search` and `search1` are *generator functions*.  While the solution is less general than mine, focusing on this specific problem, it offers another very useful feature: it returns a iterator letting us pull and process the entries individually, which can be very powerful.  And because you can simply turn the results back into an array if you don't want the iteration, it's at least as powerful

The thing to note is that Mulan's solution could easily be enhanced to handle the same sort of flexibility mine has.  The reverse is not true.  To try to make this version into a generator function would be an entire rewrite.

I'm not trying to say that Mulan's approach is universally better.  If you only ever want an array result, this version is simpler (and probably more time-efficient).  But Mulan's can be made to offer some flexibility this one simply cannot.

Comment: Very nice Scott! Same question to you as to Mulan's approach. Could this be modified to accept a twin key search? The idea being there could be might be multiple keys at the bottom level that match, and using twin keys as an input would increase the chance of a correct match. E.g, deepFindKeys(["test 2, test 3a"])(data)

Comment: The problem I see is in knowing what constitutes your target. `"test 2"` can trivially return `{"test 3a": {"tab1graph1: {...}, "test 3b": {...},, ...}`, but how would we know to descend to the next level and not even one deeper, say `"value c"`?  If you want find keys along a *path*, such as `test 2 > test 3a", then I think you need to open another question.

Comment: Ok, understood. Apologies for the delving outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Not at all.  It's often worth doing.  But when it strays too far, the best bet is opening a new question.

Comment: @ScottSauyet nice to see you as well ^_^. the predicate based approach is definitely more flexible at the call site. very nice explanation and review of the differing techniques. thanks for including me in your work.