# Return object that matches specific branch traversal

Tags: javascript, recursion, search

[This question started here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427002/how-to-return-an-object-whose-nested-objects-match-a-list-of-search-strings/)

The conversation exceeded the original scope, so asking the expanded question here.

Given this data:

```
{
"tabs-3": {
    "Collection A": {
        "Level 2": {
            "Data A": {
                "tab3graph25": {
                    "30/04": 21750,
                    "31/03": 19428,
                    "29/05": 20955
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "Collection B": {
        "Level 2": {
            "Data A": {
                "tab3graph33": {
                    "30/04": 56863,
                    "31/03": 62298,
                    "29/05": 56044
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "Collection C": {
        "Level 2": {
            "Data A": {
                "tab3graph40": {
                    "30/04": 56044,
                    "31/03": 62298,
                    "29/05": 56863
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What would a function look like that would take as it's input the holding object to search, in this case, "tabs-3", and a key set to look for, e.g., var searchList = [Collection B, Level 2, Data A] and then return "tab3graph33:{...values...}

The original starting function I have is here for reference ,

```
function searchObjectForValues(obj, searchList) {
  var matchingObjects = {};

  function recursiveSearch(currentObj, path) {
    if (typeof currentObj === 'object' && currentObj !== null) {
      for (var key in currentObj) {
        if (currentObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var value = currentObj[key];
          var currentPath = path.concat(key);

          if (searchList.includes(key)) {
            matchingObjects[key] = currentObj[key];
          }

          recursiveSearch(value, currentPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  recursiveSearch(obj, []);

  return matchingObjects;
}
```

Although the answers in the original question are much more elegant than mine.

Comment: Do you want to supply the full path, such as `['tabs-3', 'Collection B', 'Level 2', 'Data A']`?  If so there are many answers here that can help, and we can probably help you find one.  Or do you want to offer possible hints that might distinguish competing entries, such as `['Collection B', 'Data A']`?  If so, you need to explain how to recognize the nodes you actually want to return.  That is, why don't we return the object with the key `'Level 2'` or the string with the key `'29/04'` but the object with the key `'Data A'`?

Comment: I'm wondering if any confusion introduced by my question structure is due to my trying to simplify the overall implementation in the question to the point I'm just making a mess of things.

The end result I'm needing is to retrieve the bottom most object so that it can be passed off to another graphing function that accepts an object of key-value pairs. The data structure is due to how the source data is ingested, e.g., region, system, kpi, for example. It's why there can be duplicate "Data A" objects, as the same KPI is used across multiple systems. Apologies for the verbosity.

Comment: *Bottom-most* is a slippery concept.  *Leaf nodes* are clear: nodes which have no children (e.g. not Objects/Arrays.)  But there's still some ambiguity.  The earlier question seemed to ask for something which wasn't technically a JS value, which the answers interpreted to mean you wanted a object with the single key "tab1graph1" and matching value an object which had three keys with String values.  Do you just want that object with the three string key-value pairs, without the "tab1graph1" wrapper?  And if so, will this do for a definition of *bottom-most*: "having no array/object values"?

Comment: The end goal would be to pass the function "Collection B, Level 2, Data A" and have it return whatever object is at the end of that path, in this example case the object "tab3graph33": {
                    "30/04": 56863,
                    "31/03": 62298,
                    "29/05": 56044
                }

Comment: Fun question. I wrote up a little something different for this version of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a fairly simple recursive function for this.  Utility libraries usually include one, too, if you're already using something like Underscore or Ramda.

```js
const getPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? o : getPath(ps) (o && o[p])

const data = {"tabs-3": {"Collection A": {"Level 2": {"Data A": {tab3graph25: {"30/04": 21750, "31/03": 19428, "29/05": 20955}}}}, "Collection B": {"Level 2": {"Data A": {tab3graph33: {"30/04": 56863, "31/03": 62298, "29/05": 56044}}}}, "Collection C": {"Level 2": {"Data A": {tab3graph40: {"30/04": 56044, "31/03": 62298, "29/05": 56863}}}}}}


const tabs3 = data['tabs-3']
console .log ('Partial path:', getPath (['Collection B', 'Level 2', 'Data A'])(tabs3))

// or
console .log ('Full-path:', getPath (['tabs-3', 'Collection B', 'Level 2', 'Data A'])(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The first `console.log` shows how you would use this the way you seem to want, with a reference to the object in the `'tabs-3'` property of your data.  The second one shows my preferred way, using `'tabs-3'` as one more property in the list.

Comment: Seeing your full path implementation, I agree that should be the preferred method. Thank you very much for taking the time! This is must useful and instructional.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun `get` function which accepts `*` and `**` wildcards. Given this `data` -

```js
const data = {
  a: {
    b: {
      x: {y:1, z:2},
      y: {z:3},
    },
    c: {
      x: {y:4},
      y: {z:5},
    },
    d: {x:6},
  },
  b: {c: {z:7}}
}
```

We can write `get` as a recursive generator -

```js
function *get(t, path) {
  function *loop(t, path, match, wild) {
    if (path.length === 0)
      yield [match, t]
    else if (path[0] === "**")
      yield *loop(t, path.slice(1), match, true)
    else if (Object(t) === t)
      for (const k of Object.keys(t))
        if (path[0] === "*" || path[0] === k)
          yield *loop(t[k], path.slice(1), [...match, k], false)
        else if (wild)
          yield *loop(t[k], path, [...match, k], true)
  }
  yield *loop(t, path, [], false)
}
```

Search for a path starting with `a`, followed by one wildcard, followed by `x` -

```js
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["a","*","x"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```js
["a","b","x"] {"y":1,"z":2}
["a","c","x"] {"y":4}
["a","d","x"] 6
```

Search for **any** path ending in `z` -

```js
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["**","z"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```js
["a","b","x","z"] 2
["a","b","y","z"] 3
["a","c","y","z"] 5
["b","c","z"] 7
```

Get full path `a`, `c`, `x`, `y` -

```js
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["a","c","x","y"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```js
["a","c","x","y"] 4
```

Make complex patterns -

```js
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["*","b","**","y"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```js
["a","b","x","y"] 1
["a","b","y"] {"z":3}
```

Get non-existent path -

```js
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["x","y","z"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```js
// <empty result>
```

Verify the results below in your own browser -

```js
function *get(t, path) {
  function *loop(t, path, match, wild) {
    if (path.length === 0)
      yield [match, t]
    else if (path[0] === "**")
      yield *loop(t, path.slice(1), match, true)
    else if (Object(t) === t)
      for (const k of Object.keys(t))
        if (path[0] === "*" || path[0] === k)
          yield *loop(t[k], path.slice(1), [...match, k], false)
        else if (wild)
          yield *loop(t[k], path, [...match, k], true)
  }
  yield *loop(t, path, [], false)
}

const data = {
  a: {
    b: {
      x: {y:1, z:2},
      y: {z:3},
    },
    c: {
      x: {y:4},
      y: {z:5},
    },
    d: {x:6},
  },
  b: {c: {z:7}}
}

for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["a","*","x"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
  
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["**","z"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
  
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["a","c","x","y"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
  
for (const [path, value] of get(data, ["x","y","z"]))
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(path),
    JSON.stringify(value)
  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**sans generators**

Here's the same solution without using generators. The interface is identical however it always returns an array instead of an iterator -

```js
function get(t, path) {
  const loop = (t, path, match, wild) =>
    path.length === 0
      ? [[match, t]]
  : path[0] === "**"
      ? loop(t, path.slice (1), match, true)
  : Object(t) === t
      ? Object.keys(t).flatMap(k =>
          path[0] === "*" || path[0] === k
            ? loop(t[k], path.slice (1), [...match, k], false)
        : wild
            ? loop(t[k], path, [...match, k], true)
        : []
        )
  : []
  return loop(t, path, [], false)
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful.  I was considering something fairly equivalent using [pathEntries](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20pathEntries&searchOn=3), and then checking if all supplied keys are in the path.  But I got stuck on what were considered leaf nodes.  Then when the comments clarified that the OP is supplying the whole path, I went with the easy approach to that.  But yours will solve the problem more generically so long as the input path ends with the name of the node the user wants to fetch.  Very handy!

Comment: Wow, that is very handy indeed! Both of you guys took this up another level! In my use case I hadn't considered the necessity of wild card searches in the event I only am supplied the ending node.

Comment: I'm happy you find it useful. One thing I like about this implementation is it returns the matched path that relates to the value. If it's not the exact behavior you are looking for, hopefully we have both provided enough examples for you to work from as a starting point ^_^

Comment: I added a translation of the program that does the same job without generators. Hopefully this helps you understand the relationships between the two approaches and demonstrates the logic can be identical.

Comment: @ScottSauyet i was also considering the various ways to handle "leaf" nodes. Another approach could be ensuring the path is `[]` and `t` is a non-object, that would mean that path has navigated to plain value. This constraint could be added if matches were intended to be more strict.